# Ebib: note field

Tags: emacs, bibtex

Unable to save the data in the `note` field in my `.bib` file.

When I edit a `.bib` file in Ebib (in emacs), I expect to be able to fill in the `note` field and save it in the same file. However, Ebib offers to save it in some other text file (which, I believe, is not accessible with `bibtex`). Is it possible to tweak Ebib to put a simple string of text into the field and save it in the `.bib` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`note` accepts multiline values, hence must be edited just like `annote`. The manual documents further the operations with `annote`.

Comment: This was explained earlier [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75203/19901).